# Smooth out Image Vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image that I converted to a vector and plotted:

```
img = imread(image.png');
grayImage = rgb2gray(img);
grayImage(2:2:end,:)=fliplr(grayImage(2:2:end,:));

B = rot90(grayImage);
C = flipud(B);

[x,y]=size(C);
vector = reshape(C ,1,x*y);
plot(vector);
```

The problem is that although I can visually see a wave pattern, there is a lot of noise that occurs. By noise I mean the signals rapidly go up and down eventually forming a sinusoidal wave but I want to be able to just connect the crest of each spike to one another in order to create a continuous wave pattern. If anyone understands what I am trying to do, help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure about what you're asking, but the `medfilt1` median filter function might be what you're looking for, it's a 1D smoothing filter. Example usage would be:

```
vector_filt = medfilt1(vector);
```

Check out the documentation and example at http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/medfilt1.html.

Answer (score 0):

I think performing a gaussian convolution on the vector should solve your problem. Here is a link to a stack overflow question that has a very nice answer on how to do a gaussian convolution in matlab: [Gaussian Filter on a vector in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992213/gaussian-filter-on-a-vector-in-matlab)